# how to calculate time using vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I make a project car rentals but I have trouble counting time, to take the penalty when you return the car late, please help me

this is my code

```
Dim date1 As DateTime
Dim date2 As DateTime
'DateTimePicker1 = today's date 10/07/2011 11:10
'DateTimePicker2 = date back 10/07/2011 09:00

date1 = Convert.ToDateTime (Me.DateTimePicker2.Value)
date2 = Convert.ToDateTime (Me.DateTimePicker1.Value)

Dim diff As System.TimeSpan
diff = date2 - date1
Me.txtresult.text = diff.Hours & diff.Minutes
```

but the results do not correspond..

I want the result = 2 hours 10 minutes

someone help me,,, please ....

Comment: Erm, don't swap the month and the day.

Comment: How does the result not correspond? What result do you get?

Comment: Yeah, as @Hans says, one of those two date strings are in the wrong format, either you have day.month.year or you have month.day.year, you can't hope for the method to "correctly" handle both formats at the same time. Why are you even using `Convert.ToDateTime` if you have a datetimepicker? They should give you the date directly. Try just using the `.Value` property directly and don't pass it through `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Comment: And, it would help tremendously if you posted *what you got* as a result.

Answer (score 3):

For the case of 2 hours and 10 minutes, `diff.Hours & diff.Minutes` returns `210`, because `&` concatenates the string representations of the numbers `2` and `10`. To format the string the way you want, use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
String.Format("{0} hours {1} minutes", diff.Hours, diff.Minutes)
```

This is going to show unexpected results when the time is over one day. For example, 25 hours and 5 minutes would show as “1 hours 5 minutes”. To fix that, you either need to check the value of `diff.Days` or use `diff.TotalHours`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming i read your question correctly, since `date1 > date2`, then you will need to use:

```
Dim diff = date1 - date2
```

otherwise you'll get back -2 hours and -10 minutes... :)

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the earlier date from later date (note DateTime has a Subtract method if you like). Also, remember to account for days. To illustrate the concept, the following shows five ways to express approximately the same time span.

Note that the TimeSpan member properties like Days, Hours, Minutes, etc, represent the respective integral part of the time span (i.e., Hours = 0 - 23, Minutes = 0 - 59) whereas the members like TotalHours, TotalMinutes, etc, are representative of the whole span. Hence this is why they are doubles...

```vb
'Assuming DateTimePicker1 has the earlier date...
Dim date1 As DateTime = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value

'Assuming DateTimePicker2 has the later date...
Dim date2 As DateTime = Me.DateTimePicker2.Value

'Get the difference (TimeSpan)...
Dim diff As System.TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)

'Some different ways to express the resulting TimeSpan...
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} days, {1} hrs, {2} min, {3} sec", diff.Days, diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds))
Console.WriteLine("total days = " & diff.TotalDays)
Console.WriteLine("total hours = " & diff.TotalHours)
Console.WriteLine("total minutes = " & diff.TotalMinutes)
Console.WriteLine("total seconds = " & diff.TotalSeconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are parse strings with different date formats, you should specify what the format is:

```
date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(Me.txttanggalkembali.Value, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(Me.DateTimePicker1.Value, "MM'.'dd'.'yyyy HH':'mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to use the [TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) and [TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) properties instead.

Comment: I was almost going to post the same answer, but I think it's incorrect: `TotalMinutes` can be > 59 because it "contains" the hours. If you want to display h:mm, I believe that `Hours` and `Minutes` are the correct properties to use.

Comment: Yep @stakx, I think you're right; that was off the top of my head but I didn't check to make sure before I posted.